# Haskell - Parsec Parsing <p> element

Tags: html, parsing, haskell, functional-programming, parsec

I'm using [Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html) and [Text.XHtml](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/xhtml/3000.2.0.1/doc/html/Text-XHtml-Transitional.html) to parse an input like this:

```
This is the first paragraph example\n
with two lines\n
\n
And this is the second paragraph\n
```

And my output should be:

`<p>This is the first paragraph example\n
with two lines\n</p>
<p>And this is the second paragraph\n</p>`

I defined:

```
line= do{
        ;t<-manyTill (anyChar) newline
        ;return t
        }

paragraph = do{
        t<-many1 (line) 
        ;return ( p << t )
    }
```

But it returns:

`<p>This is the first paragraph example\n
with two lines\n\n And this is the second paragraph\n</p>`

What is wrong? Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [documentation for manyTill](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v%3AmanyTill), it runs the first argument *zero or more times*, so 2 newlines in a row is still valid and your `line` parser will not fail.

You're probably looking for something like `many1Till` (like `many1` versus `many`) but it doesn't seem to exist in the Parsec library, so you may need to roll your own: (warning: I don't have ghc on this machine, so this is completely untested)

```
many1Till p end = do
    first <- p
    rest  <- p `manyTill` end
    return (first : rest)
```

or a terser way:

```
many1Till p end = liftM2 (:) p (p `manyTill` end)
```

Comment: The problem is if you use this with `anyChar` as `p` it still matches two newlines, because `first <- p` consumes the first newline.

Comment: As a point of personal preference, I'd write that instead as: `many1Till p end = (:) <$> p <*> manyTill p end`. The `do` notation rarely improves Parsec-based code, to my eye. (Oops, didn't see your edit--the `liftM2` version is equivalent to mine, of course)

Answer (score 2):

The `manyTill` combinator [matches **zero or more** occurrences of its first argument](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.0.0/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Combinator.html#v%3AmanyTill), according to the documentation, so `line` will happily accept a blank line, which means that `many1 line` will consume everything up to the final newline in the file, rather than stopping at a double newline as it seems you intended.